# AngularJS SEO for static webpages (S3 CDN)

Tags: seo, javascript, ajax, amazon-s3

I've been looking into ways to improve SEO for angularJS apps that are hosted on a CDN like Amazon S3 (i.e. simple storage with no backend). Most of the solutions out there, [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org), [prerender.io](https://prerender.io), [seo.js](http://getseojs.com) etc., rely on a backend to recognise the `?_escaped_fragment_` url that the crawler generates and then fetch the relevant page from elsewhere. Even [grunt-html-snapshot](https://github.com/localnerve/html-snapshots) ultimately needs you to do this, even though you generate the snapshot pages ahead of time.

This [solution](http://www.dave.cx/post/23/prerendering-angular-s3/) is basically relying on using cloudflare as a reverse proxy, which seems a bit of a waste given that most of the security apparatus etc. that their service provides is totally redundant for a static site. Setting up a reverse proxy myself as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383239/single-page-app-amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-prerender-io-how-to-set-up) also seems problematic given that it would require either i) routing all AngularJS apps I need static html for through one proxy server which would potentially hamper performance or ii) setting up a separate proxy server for each app, at which point I may as well set up a backend, which isn't affordable at the scale I am working.

Is there anyway of doing this, or are statically hosted AngularJS apps with great SEO basically impossible until google updates their crawlers?

(Reposted from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043336/angularjs-seo-for-static-webpages-s3-cdn)).

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue if this is going to work well, but neither have I if it's about AngularJS and SEO in general. There is very little evidence it works the way it is supposed to do.

I would suggest leaving PhantomJS in the dark, it is known to have issues and is not very lightweight. Also considering you don't want to write/set up a backend I would use Firefox to use an awesome feature: [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML), to capture the html content at any given moment in JavaScript and use the Amazone CDN API to upload the content to a different html page.

The thing that rests is to let the crawler know to index the other page. This is the tricky part since you don't want to have a backend, hence you can't use the `?_escaped_fragment_` url as you said it. I would use just a [canonical relation](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) between the pages using a link tag. But remember, I am not completely sure it will work.

Comment: Thanks for that link to the canonical relation page, that could potentially be very helpful.

Comment: @advert2013: You're welcome. Keep in mind that you'll have to look into it, because it might not work since the content of the two pages differ to much.